# how to load (mov) a class variable into cpu register

Tags: c++, assembly

I would like to load an int value defined as class member to eax cpu register. smt like this:

```
class x
{
    int a;

    x() { a=5; }

    do_stuff()
    {
        __asm
        {
            mov eax, a; // mov a varbiale content into register
        };
    }
};
```

how can I do that with any variable in any class? thanks...

Comment: Is this for fun? I sure hope so.

Comment: no not for fun, but for performance... I can do this for this example, but it won't solve my problem:
mov ebx, [this];
mov ecx, [ebx];

Comment: What makes you think this is going to help performance? That's seriously misguided. Compilers emit assembly, not you; they'll do a far better job of it, too. Use a profiler, after your program is *finished and correct*, then use the profiler to make *algorithmic* changes, not binary changes.

Comment: @GMan: You're giving compilers too much credit. Mapping source code to assembly is a pretty complex operation, and I'm sure there are instances where a keen pair of human eyes might see something a compiler might have missed.

Comment: @codebolt: Yes, complex enough where humans tend to not do as well. (Yes, there are exceptions. No, they don't apply to anyone here. If they do, you know who you are.) In any case, that's the *last* optimization step to take: optimize the algorithm first.

Comment: @GMan  I have written 2 blocks of code, first one is asm, and second one is C++. I run these two blocks seperately and asm block is running faster. That's why I am writing a small asm code, this code needs performance.

Comment: @MCA: Did you compile with optimizations? Are the two actually equivalent? I'd be very impressed if what you say is actually true.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using gcc or icc, this does exactly what you want:

```
class x
{
    int a;

    x() { a=5; }

    do_stuff()
    {
        asm("mov %0, %%eax; // mov a varbiale content into register \n"
            :
            : "r" (a)
            : "%eax"
           );


    }
};
```

An explanation of rgister constrains and clobber lists is at http://www.ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html if you are still interested. On MS VC I would not recommend using inline assembly, because the MS compiler is not good at mixing inline and generated assmbely and produces a lot of overhead.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to load a class variable into a register is by letting the compiler do it for you.

Since the compiler always have to assume the worst, when it comes to reading things from memory, it might be forced to read the value from a class member multiple times, despite the fact that *you* know that the value has not changed.

For example, in the code below in the function `do_stuff`, the compiler can not assume that the value of `mX` is unchanged over the call to `foo()`. Hence, it is not allowed to place it in a processor register.

```
int glob;
int glob2;
void foo();

class Test
{
public:
  Test(int x) : mX(x) { }
  void do_stuff();
private:
  int mX;
};


void Test::do_stuff()
{
  glob = mX;
  foo();
  glob2 = mX;
}
```

On the other hand, in the following case, the source code is written so that `tmp` can't change over the function call, so the compiler is safe to place it in a register.

```
void Test::do_stuff()
{
  int tmp = mX;
  glob = tmp;
  foo();
  glob2 = tmp;
}
```

When it comes to inline assembler, I would strongly discourage you from using it. When introducing C++ the situation is even worse, as the underlying representation of a class object is not as straight-forward as that of a C struct (which must be laid out in memory exactly as declared). This mean that a slight change in the class or a migration to a newer compiler could break your code.

Comment: It's a typo, it should read `C struct`. I've updated the answer, thanks!

Comment: I come up with this solution: There'a only 3 things I need to load so I defined local 3 variables before asm block and use those variables

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the address of of the instance of class "x" you're working with (mov eax,this), and the offset of "a" relative to the start of "x" (offsetof macro).

It's a lot easier if you just add "a" or "&a" as a parameter of the do_stuff() function.